# Trigger Azure Function by inserting (adding) new row into table, SQL Server Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to trigger Azure Function by inserting new row into table (using SQL Server Database).
Or, is it possible create Logic App to inform us, in case of new record has been added into table, SQL Server database (e.g once the new record is added to send new info email)

Comment: There's no way I'm aware of that lets you send alerts out from an Azure SQL Database. So you'd have to set up a monitoring service. Probably the way to do that would be Azure Automation. It uses Powershell. You can easily set up a query that looks for new rows (you'll have to determine how something is "new").

I've put this in as a comment because I've never done this, so I don't think it should be answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Azure Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid/) as stated on [this](https://www.codit.eu/blog/2017/08/21/exploring-azure-event-grid/) article "Extend existing workflows by triggering a Logic App once there is a new record in your database".

You can also create a Logic App to poll the table and add an action item to call the Azure function or a RESTful call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Alberto, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: According to the author of the article linked in this answer where "Extend existing workflows by triggering a Logic App once there is a new record in your database" is quoted from, this is not yet possible: https://twitter.com/TomKerkhove/status/973564339578908672

Comment: Is this still not doable via a push mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has the same question, 
If you are using SQL Azure, you can use the SQL Connector trigger for Logic Apps

> With this connector trigger, you can kick off your Logic Apps whenever
>   a row is inserted or modified in a SQL Azure Database table.
>
> 1. You have to select the appropriate trigger.
> 2. Create your connection (if you have not already) or select an existing connection.
> 3. Then, select the table from the drop-down.
> 4. You can also choose to further limit the rows returned by specifying a filter.
>
> Currently the connector has some limitations
>
> - It does not work for on-premises SQL Server
> - Table must have an IDENTITY column for the new row trigger
> - Table must have a ROWVERSION (a.k.a. TIMESTAMP) column for the modified row trigger

Obtained from here:
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/