# Trigger Azure Function when an entry created in SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would like understand whether we can trigger an Azure Function when an entry is created in a SQL database?

I know it's possible with a Logic App.

Comment: You could always use a Logic App to be triggered, and then call your Azure Function from that Logic App ....

Comment: at this moment there's no way to get your function triggered by changes in sql database. In the future, maybe it will be possible through Event Grid..

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022-11-17 there is a new feature on AzFn called ["trigger Azure SQL pro Functions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp) matched with a new AzureSQL feature called "change tracking".

"The Azure SQL trigger uses SQL change tracking functionality to monitor a SQL table for changes and trigger a function when a row is created, updated, or deleted."

Quote:
[Change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp#set-up-change-tracking-required) is enabled on the database and on the table:

SQL

```
ALTER DATABASE [SampleDatabase]
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ToDo]
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING;
The SQL trigger binds to a IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<T>>, a list of SqlChange objects each with 2 properties:
```

AzFn:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Sql;

namespace AzureSQL.ToDo
{
    public static class ToDoTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("ToDoTrigger")]
        public static void Run(
            [SqlTrigger("[dbo].[ToDo]", ConnectionStringSetting = "SqlConnectionString")]
            IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<ToDoItem>> changes,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            foreach (SqlChange<ToDoItem> change in changes)
            {
                ToDoItem toDoItem = change.Item;
                logger.LogInformation($"Change operation: {change.Operation}");
                logger.LogInformation($"Id: {toDoItem.Id}, Title: {toDoItem.title}, Url: {toDoItem.url}, Completed: {toDoItem.completed}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More samples for the Azure SQL trigger are available in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-sql-extension/tree/main/samples/samples-csharp).

Answer (score 1):

Except for using Azure Logic App with a SQL trigger as the offical tutorial [`Automate workflows for SQL Server or Azure SQL Database by using Azure Logic Apps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure) said, there is the other feasible solution to create a DML trigger for a `FOR`/`AFTER` `INSERT` event and send a web request from SQL Database to an Azure Function with HTTP trigger.

As references, please refer to the two documents below.

1. DML trigger statements [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [What? Calling an API from Database?](https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/how-to-fire-a-web-request-from-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Logic App has a connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure) for both On-Prem as well as Azure SQL. This will trigger when new rows are added

Have a look at this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115693/trigger-azure-function-by-inserting-adding-new-row-into-table-sql-server-data).

Comment: I am looking for Azure Function Triggers, Not Logic App

Comment: Then there is no trigger as of now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings

Comment: The Azure SQL trigger for Azure Functions is now currently in [preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql)!

Answer (score 0):

You can find all supported triggers and bindings in the Azure Functions documentation: [Azure Functions triggers and bindings concepts - Supported Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings). Azure SQL is *not* in the list of supported triggers.

Taken from [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitagarwal/2018/01/11/azure-function-apps-trigger-in-azure-sql-sql-server-to-execute-azure-function/),

> In order to make an azure function trigger on a SQL change, there can be two possible ways.
>
> 1. Defining Custom Binding in Azure functions
> 2. If not the binding on Azure Functions side, then it can be a SQL trigger invoking an Azure Functions HTTP trigger.

Another scenario would be to change the back-end that updates the SQL and have it (also) push a message on a queue, which in turn triggers your Function.