# Alternative to trigger Azure Functions or AppService based on a table row insert into Azure SQL MI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to trigger Azure Functions or AppService webapp whenever an insert operation is performed against a table on Azure SQL MI?

if not, is there a way to trigger applications outside Azure SQL rather than using LogicApp? I want to avoid LogicApp because it requries using one more application, and it is still using polling.

Link below said it is not for Azure functions

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/16711846-sql-azure-trigger-support

Link below suggests using LogicApp.

[Trigger Azure Function by inserting (adding) new row into table, SQL Server Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115693/trigger-azure-function-by-inserting-adding-new-row-into-table-sql-server-data)

Answer (score 1):

Today, in Azure SQL, there is no such possibility. The closest option is to create a Timer Trigger Azure Function that checks if there has been any changes in the table you want to monitor (using Change Tracking, for example).

If you are using Azure SQL MI instead, you could create a SQLCLR procedure that calls an Azure Function via an HTTP request or, another option, via Azure Event Hubs or Azure Event Grid

Comment: Azure SQL Managed Instance is used. But SQLCLR is probably not used. Timer Trigger on Function seem easy to implement. Could you elaborate on Azure Event Hubs/Grid? Any link would be appreciated.

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/MadeiraData/ClrHttpRequest. It will work on SQL MI. Event Hubs and Event Grid support an HTTP endpoint so you can call it. Or you can just call the Azure Function, as you prefer. Just make sure that SQL MI network configuration allows you to connect to public internet endpoint.

Comment: Do I need ClrHttpRequest to call Azure Event Hubs/Grid? I am not sure how to use this tool. I would prefer tools from Microsoft if possible?

Comment: There are no tool from Microsoft to do that AFAIK. The ClrHttpRequest just shows how you can create your own solution using .NET. You can use the available code to get inspiration and do something on your own, so that you can 100% trust it.

Answer (score 0):

There have been several feature requests for triggering Azure functions based on changes to at Azure SQL database. For example:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/365

It seems that they are not prioritizing it, since it is possible to implement this functionality using logic apps.